# Can't find exe in command prompt

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I've created a "hello world" program on notepad++, executed it in the command prompt as well. Which shows up but not as an exe. Help please, my path is set correctly as well. I just want to locate and execute it through my command prompt.

Comment: What are you compiling/coding with?

Comment: "Which shows up but not as an exe" - begs the question, *what does it "show up" as?*

Comment: I removed the code since it technically has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following (if you are using g++):

```
gcc -Wall -g -o Arithmetic.exe Arithmetic.c
```

From http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html

Comment: I doubt he's using g++, he's compiling C (though of course it'd still work provided the file name is correct).

Comment: Doesn't gcc have the same options?

Comment: Yes, at least the options you've specified, which is why I said it'd still work. Though his file likely ends in .c, not .cpp.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect what you've stated

Comment: My file shwos up as TwoIntegers.c on the directory, But not as TwoIntegers.exe. I am using Notepad++, the gcc compiler, and the command line. Thanks guys!